# Не загружается OpenAL и soft_oal.dll в monogame/Xna

Tags: c#, xna

Когда запускаю проект выводит ошибку на Load() : " Failed to init OpenALSoundController " и "Exception: Failed to load library: soft_oal.dll". Пробовал переустанавливать OpenAL - не помогло. Как исправить? Очень нужна помощь.

Comment: Обычно ьакое бывает, когда 64-битную библиотеку пытаются загрузить в 32-битное приложение, или наоборот.

Comment: @aepot , не помогло